# Image library for PHP that works with metadata, resizes and crops

Tags: php, image, resize, metadata

Do you know any PHP library that can work with the metadata of an image (author, copyright info, location... etc) and also do resizing and cropping? I use ImageMagick but I couldn't find anything about retrieving and working with metadata of an image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

imagemagick. For metadata check here
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8906

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

- [Exif](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php)
- [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)